# Asp.net MVC + dropzoneJS file upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropzone.js

I use DropzoneJS with MVC. The file uploads fine, but action will not display another view, neither will display another view after redirected to another action. Just stays on the same view it was called from.

Action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if(file != null)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            if (file.ContentLength > 0 && ext == ".txt")
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                if (fileName != null)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }

        return View("Report");   

        // This will redirect to action but will not display another view either:
        // return RedirectToAction("Report"); 
     }
```

View called from:

```
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="/Dashboard/FileUpload" class="dropzone clickable" id="demo-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell your browser to do the redirect, if you use dropzone to upload files asyncronsly. With a async call to your MVC controller, MVC can't tell the browser to change page. You can do a redirect in javascript after dropzone have uploaded the files with the complete event:

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  window.location = "./Dashboard/Report/";
});
```